Do std::(unordered_)map and std::(unordered_)set share code?
Let's say that I care about binary size, I already use std::map, and I need a set. Instead of using std::set<T>, I could use std::map<T, bool>. Will that help, or is common code already used under the hood?
I doubt that the C++ standard says something about sharing code, so it might vary between implementations, but I assume there's some common practice.

That is Implemetation detail and you should not rely on that.

std::map<T, bool> and std::map<T, V> would be two different classes anyway. There's also a difference between shared code and shared compiled code (e.g. std::less<T> would be shared but also would likely be inlined).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai It’s in the first sentence.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai the real reason for the question is that I'm curious, I hope that's OK.

@KonradRudolph first sentence "I need a set" I ask what for? why? why not simply use the map?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai No. The first sentence is “… I care about binary size …”. That’s an entirely reasonable reason: it’s a common code size optimisation technique to merge common code of class templates by having them inherit a common base with the implementation.

its ok. Asking for clarification is often misunderstood as aggression and denial, nothing like that intended.

@KonradRudolph I got it. They do not need a set containing the same elements as the map. They use a map and elsewhere they need a set. Its all in the question and I could have read more carefully.

Templates do not share code in final executable. Template is just recipe hot to create code for given template parameters (usually types). To reduce executable size it is better to avoid use of templates.

This is a thing that you will have to measure and see. You are right that std::map<T, std::monostate> is more similar to std::map<T, U> than std::set<T> is, as the underlying comparisons have to go via value.first, rather than being directly value.
Afaik, the main implementations do implement all the associative containers with one base class template, and similarly all the unordered associative containers with one class template. However, these are all templates, so there will be differing amounts of object code re-use arising from that.

I did a quick measurement with Visual Studio. Using std::unordered_set<int> instead of std::unordered_map<int, std::monostate> (while std::unordered_map<int, int> is already used) added 1536 bytes, which is quite negligible. So I assume that you're right and there's a base class template that's shared between the two.

As you've observed, this is up to the implementation.
That said, yes, in at least some widely used compilers (e.g., gcc) set and map use a shared implementation.
For example, here's the underlying red/black tree implementation that gcc uses for both set and map:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_tree.h
Here's the part of the map header where that's put to use:
      typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Select1st<value_type>,
               key_compare, _Pair_alloc_type> _Rep_type;

      /// The actual tree structure.
      _Rep_type _M_t;

